# How to make network resources available locally before running a script?

Tags: windows

I need to run a batch script which expects folders locally. It runs a Python process that uses `os.listdir` etc. However this particular folder I am interested in only there in a Network Folder. So is it possible for me to access Network Resource just before running it and then closing it later on?

For **Services** we have an option in Windows Services that says "Log On As" which can be used to access remote machine and do some operation on the files there. I think it is called [Service Logon Accounts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/AD/service-logon-accounts). Would it possible to do the same for a simple batch script i.e a simple **Process**?

---

Should I use the `net use` command for this? I saw some solutions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/client-access-to-network-resources) but `net use` is the probably the simplest way to do this?

```
net use \\RemoteComputer\c$ password /user:DOMAIN\remoteUsername
program.bat
net use \\RemoteComputer\c$ /d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some conditional [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) logic and check whether or not the UNC path to that resource exist or not. If it does not exist, you will put it in a loop so it keeps going back to the routine to keep running the recheck over and over until it does exist. Once it finds the UNC path and verifies it is accessible, this indicates this resource is availbale, the rest of your batch logic can run and then you can [Exit](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) the process once the other logic runs.

---

### Script

```
@ECHO ON

:: -- Check network share and folder is accessible 
:NetworkAccessible
::ping -n 06 127.0.0.1>nil
IF NOT EXIST "\\<ServerName>\<ShareName>\Folder" GOTO :NetworkAccessible

<Rest of Logic>
<Rest of Logic>

EXIT
```

> **Note:** *You can remove the two colons on the `::ping -n 06 127.0.0.1>nil` line and this will give it a 5 second delay before checking again but the number can be increased or decreased.*

---

### Further Resources

- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Goto](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [Exit](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)

Comment: Thanks, friend. So you are talking about looping until the network is accessible which is a good thing to have. But how to authenticate the resource? Can I just use `net use` for that? I have updated the code example.

Comment: @Nishant The way I've done that is identical to your updated example: `NET USE \\RemoteComputer\c$ <password> /user:Domain\UserName` and then after that runs, the `IF NOT EXIST` logic should be able to access once available. Are you having an issue or getting any error messages, etc. using that method? I'm happy to help more if needed so just let me know. I also do the `NET USE` with the `/D` switch as your example shows too afterwards.